# Docker MongoDB shell script failed while connecting

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I would like to execute some scripts after mounting MongoDB image from Docker. But, i get the message :

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.14
connecting to: mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-10-12T16:11:56.382+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't 
connect to server 0.0.0.0:27017, address resolved to 0.0.0.0 :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:263:13
@(connect):1:6
```

From the following shell :

```
#!/bin/bash

##
# Create MongoDB admin user
##
mongo --host 0.0.0.0<<EOF
use admin;
db.createUser({user: "obfuscated", pwd: "obfuscated",roles: [{role: 
"userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin"}]});
EOF

##
# Create Database admin user
##
mongo --host 0.0.0.0 -u obfuscated -p obfuscated --authenticationDatabase 
admin <<EOF
use my_database;
db.createUser( { "user" : "obfuscated",  "pwd": "obfuscated","roles" : 
[{ "role": "dbOwner", "db": "easystock" },{"role" : "readWrite","db" : 
"my_database"}]});
EOF
```

The Dockerfile is the following :

```
FROM mongo:3

##
# Runs scripts
##
##
# Copy the update bash
##
RUN mkdir -p /home/bin/repository
RUN cd /home/bin
COPY createUsers ./
COPY updateDatabase ./
RUN chmod a+x createUsers
RUN chmod a+x updateEasyStock
RUN ./createUsers
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install curl
RUN ./updateDatabase
```

Don't now what happen...

Regards,

Jean-Luc

Answer (score 0):

You should run the script at entrypoint when a process is up and running and accept the connection, during build time the mongo process is not running and each instruction using RUN directive run in its own shell.

So these will not work that is mentioned in your Dockerfile.

```
RUN ./createUsers
RUN ./updateDatabase
```

Also, change the host to the localhost of the container that i.e `--host 0.0.0.0` to `-- host localhost`.

What I would suggest to copy these script to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` and then left everything on the official image.

```
COPY createUsers /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY updateDatabase /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

> When a container is started for the first time **it will execute files
>   with extensions** **`.sh`** and **`.js`** that are found in
>   `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. Files will be executed in alphabetical
>   order. .js files will be executed by mongo using the database
>   specified by the `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE` variable, if it is present, or
>   test otherwise. **You may also switch databases within the .js script**.

[Initializing a fresh mongo container instance](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo)

Comment: sure let me know if there is any issue or you can accept if its working.

Comment: ... after copying scripts in the correct folder, i had some troubles with the container... So, i'll keep your answer for trying later. Will tell you if it's ok....

Comment: Thx for your advices @Adiii I updated my scripts and created a brand new Dockerfile, as a new docker-compose then... after hours, i have a full featured MongoDB with my update scripts